# Node - LiveReload Capabilities

Tags: node.js, livereload

I am learning Node.js. I am trying to build a basic website for the sake of learning. In an effort to do this, I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
./
  dist/
  node_modules/
  src/
    res/
      css/
        core.css
        theme.css
    routes/
      index.js
    views/
      home/
        index.html
    server.js
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

This app uses Express for the middleware. I can successfully load the app when I visit http://localhost:3000. I am now trying to integrate LiveReload.

For some background, my gulpfile.js file looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var css = require('gulp-cssnano');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var input = {
    js : [],
    css: [ 
        'src/res/css/core.css',
        'src/res/css/theme.css'
    ],
    html: [ 'src/**/*.html' ]
};

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(clean, buildCss, buildHtml, watch));

function buildCss() {
    return gulp
        .src(input.css)
        .pipe(concat('site.css'))
        .pipe(css())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/res/css'))
    ;        
}

function buildHtml() {
    return gulp
        .src(input.html)
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    ;
}

function reload() {
    livereload.reload();
}

function watch() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch([ input.css, input.js, input.html ], reload);
}
```

The important part here is when some CSS gets changed, I need to rebuild the CSS so that it all gets put into `site.css`. My index.html file reference `site.css`. My server.js file looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// setup the middleware
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// setup livereload
var livereload = require('express-livereload');
livereload(app, config={});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/res/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/res', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'res')));

// setup the routing
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));    
});
module.exports = app;
```

If I manually start the app from the command line using `node dist/server.js` I can successfully visit "http://localhost:3000". However, if I run `gulp` and then visit "http://localhost:3000", I get an "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED", which makes sense because I'm trying to use live-reload. Still, if I visit "http://localhost:35729/", I just see the following:

```
{
  minilr: "Welcome",
  version: "0.1.8"
}
```

That I do not understand. I do not understand why I'm seeing this JSON (or where it is even coming from). I was expecting to get my index.html file. Any help to get this resolved would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also: aren't you missing `var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin')` in your gulpfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are receiving an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is because when you visit your app, Express redirects all traffic to 'routes', which points to your top directory:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes)
```

You need to change that to:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes)
```

And in your `./routes/index.js` file, have something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home/index');
});
module.exports = router;
```

On a side note, I would switch to browser-sync, which would make the whole process a lot easier:

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create();

// our browser-sync config + nodemon chain
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    bs.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:3000",
        browser: "chromium-browser",
        port: 4000,
    });
});

// the real action
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch('./views/**/*.html', bs.reload);
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.js', bs.reload);
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.css', bs.reload);
});
```

**Don't forget to `npm install --save browser-sync` before!**

Replace `bs.reload` by your appropriate gulp tasks if you need some pre/post processing, while always including `bs.reload` at the end or as a subsequent task.

Finally, you should also install and create a test project using the [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) which will help you a lot with regard project and code structure. Enjoy!